# Reading CSV in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, fgetcsv

I'd my project in Symfony **1.4 (Please keep version in mind)**

As a new requirement, in admin panel, admin need to upload bulk images. For that, admin will provide a zip file with images and a csv file with required info about images.

I earlier handled reading CSV task in core PHP using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). However I'm interested to know if there is any plugin/build-in support in symfony 1.4 as better way (in terms of performance/speed) of reading CSV task or looping through [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) in model/controller is only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't think there is a function or a class that could be much faster than using the PHP function.

I've perform a quick search, only 2 plugins exists:

- [sfCsvPlugin](https://github.com/toaotc/sfCsvPlugin)
- [tmCsvPlugin](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/tmCsvPlugin)

But they both use `fgetcsv` to read each line. You still can use them to have a kind of clean & short way to read a CSV file.

They both have an interesting function that allow you to export as a CSV file a single table from your model (using Propel in sfCsvPlugin and Doctrine in tmCsvPlugin).